# How to list all iso files of a particular datastore using powercli in VMware vSphere

Tags: vmware, datastore, vsphere, powercli

I am trying to list all iso files in ISO directory of a particular datastore in VMware vSphere using powercli. I am able to list all the isos in all the datastores using the below command though but not able to do so for a particular datastore.

dir vmstores:\ -Recurse -Include *.iso | Select Name,FolderPath

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to do something more like:

```
dir vmstore:\datacentername\datastorename -Recurse -Include *.iso | Select Name, FolderPath
```

Comment: I tried that. Its not working. It says the path does not exist.

Comment: I just updated the example code, you should be using vmstore and not vmstores

Answer (score 1):

I found that the below set of commands worked.

$datastoreName = 'enter_name_of_datastore'

$ds = Get-Datastore -Name $datastoreName

New-PSDrive -Location $ds -Name DS -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root '\' | Out-Null

Get-ChildItem -Path DS:\ISO -Include *.iso -Recurse | Select Name,FolderPath

Remove-PSDrive -Name DS -Confirm:$false